# UV Preview Texture Not Applying In Shading Tab

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv

Im Fairly new to this and ive been texturing some models ive made using UVW Unwrapping to texture
which has worked up until now. For some reason blender wont allow me to apply the same material ive been using to test my UV unwraps this whole time ive been using blenders UV preview texture but now it just refuses to apply to any other parts of my object whatsoever it darkens the colour of the model and then doesnt show the actual checker pattern and i cant seem to find any awnsers as to why

Any Help Would be appriciated

[image: Shading Tab showing material ive tried to apply]

Comment: Maybe you've not correctly unwrapped your object, could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? Use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or another platform like workupload

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=eVzd4SA9" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/eVzd4SA9/) Is that right?

Comment: Ah yeah no i didnt unwrap it yeah its working now thanks im just an idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not correctly unwrapped your object, it only shows a grey part of your image, unwrap again.

Comment: Yeah that did it cheers mate